# Hint: Show that $B \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow B^{c} \in \mathcal{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space, and $Y \in \mathcal{B}$

Define $\mathcal{B}:=\{Y\cap A: A \in \mathcal A\}$

I am in the process of proving that $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ is a measure space. I am stuck on the $-^{c}$ stability, however, namely showing that:

$B \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow B^{c} \in \mathcal{B}$

My ideas:

Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$, then there exists as above, $B:=Y\cap A$.
$B^{c}=(Y\cap A)^{c}=Y^{c}\cup A^{c}$

Now, I am confused as to whether $Y^{c}=Y -Y$ or $Y^{c}=X -Y$ and the same for $A^{c}=Y-A$ or $A^{c}=X-A$

Comment: Best to avoid notation $A^c$. For $\cal A$ to be a sigma algebra on $X$ we need $A\in{\cal A}\implies X-A\in{\cal A}$.  For $\cal B$ to be a sigma algebra on $Y$ we need $B\in{\cal B}\implies Y-B\in{\cal B}$.

Answer (score 2):

You're taking the complement with respect to $Y$, whice you should usually specify when writing "$\cdot ^c$". Here $B^{c}$ in $Y$ means $Y\setminus B$, which is written by $Y\cap (X\setminus B)$.  You should verify why this is indeed in $\mathcal{B}$.